# Why are plasmashell and kwin running even in multi-user (console) mode?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, kde, kwin

I'm running Arch Linux on my main work machine.  I discovered this curiosity today when having issues with baloo (file indexer for KDE Plasma) where it was hogging up all RAM and CPU cycles indexing files.  At first I didn't realize baloo could be disabled using `balooctl` and my first thought was to set the systemd target to multi-user and reboot into it, just to get my system to a usable state with no bells & whistles while I use my Windows machine on the desk right next to it to look for solutions and/or check for available updates.

However, when I rebooted into a console and ran `htop` to make sure there were no runaway processes, I noticed that several KDE applications - including /usr/bin/kwin_x11 and /usr/bin/plasmashell were still running.  I have since rebooted the machine several times (into multi-user non-graphical target), and to my confusion, all of the usual KDE programs are still running with each boot.

```
myuser      557  0.1  0.0 126264 11868 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/bin/startplasma-x11
myuser      559  3.0  0.4 436832 77128 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop-host --host-config=- --audio-pipe-nam
myuser      564  7.5  0.0   7240  3168 ?        Ss   15:45   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog --fork --print-pid 4 --print-address 6 --session
myuser      598  0.0  0.0   2232    88 ?        S    15:45   0:00 /usr/lib/kf5/start_kdeinit --kded +kcminit_startup
myuser      599  0.8  0.1  99348 21548 ?        Ss   15:45   0:00 kdeinit5: Running...
myuser      600  1.8  0.2 277116 40360 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/lib/kf5/klauncher --fd=10
myuser      614  5.6  0.4 1181388 73856 ?       Sl   15:45   0:00 kded5
myuser      633  1.3  0.2 281060 41548 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /bin/kaccess
myuser      637  0.6  0.1 244092 25996 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/bin/plasma_session
myuser      641  2.3  0.2 276668 40288 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/bin/kglobalaccel5
myuser      644  1.6  0.2 278608 42904 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /bin/ksmserver
myuser      654  0.0  0.0 154920  5128 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf-service
myuser      660 39.2  1.0 1367224 172196 ?      Rl   15:45   0:01 /usr/bin/kwin_x11 -session 10d7766465000156399548600000006890006_1589829814_936193
myuser      664 94.0  1.8 1956624 299036 ?      Sl   15:45   0:04 /usr/bin/plasmashell
myuser      666  1.6  0.2 426840 42636 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/lib/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1
myuser      668  0.4  0.1 224136 20528 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /bin/xembedsniproxy
polkitd      682  3.4  0.1 1659456 22072 ?       Ssl  15:45   0:00 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
myuser      691  0.2  0.1 225388 21344 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /bin/gmenudbusmenuproxy
myuser      694  2.4  0.2 276000 40512 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/lib/DiscoverNotifier
myuser      702  0.0  0.0 946668  6452 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
rtkit        704  0.0  0.0 152716  2912 ?        SNsl 15:45   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit-daemon
myuser      719  1.0  0.2 465040 33368 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/lib/kactivitymanagerd
myuser      734  6.6  0.5 1252424 89120 ?       Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/bin/kmix -session 10d7766465000156407103200000310090009_1589829814_895627
myuser      749  0.4  0.0 349940 13824 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
myuser      751  5.0  0.3 458396 58120 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/bin/korgac -session 10d7766465000156407103200000310090010_1589829814_895873
myuser      760  0.2  0.1 217360 19756 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/lib/kf5/kscreen_backend_launcher
root         766  6.0  0.0 248664  9472 ?        Ssl  15:45   0:00 /usr/lib/upowerd
myuser      772  7.6  0.5 995924 96440 ?        Sl   15:45   0:00 /usr/bin/yakuake -session 10d7766465000157608183800000007360008_1589829814_896311
```

How is this? This is with `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target && reboot`. Above is some of the output of `ps aux`. Is it normal for KDE Plasma (and hence, Xorg) to run with systemd's boot target set to multi-user?
Note: I have Chrome Remote Desktop installed on this machine as I've used it a bit for working from home.  Could that have anything to do with it?

EDIT: About a half hour after I posted this, I thought maybe it's because:

```
1. I'm using lightdm
2. I did NOT disable lightdm.service `sudo systemctl disable lightdm.service`
3. Something something config files?... I checked `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and there doesn't seem to be anything that would automatically start any plasma services in there.
```

Among all of the processes listed, I didn't actually see Xorg itself, but I assumed it would have to be running for so many plasma processes to have started.

Comment: As a first step, I'd check if LightDM and Xorg were also running. This may tell something about how the processes you are seeing are started. (And... no, I see that on a fresh Arch with SDDM (sorry, I can't tell about LightDM) and KDE, when the default systemd target is `multi-user`, no Plasma or Xorg processes are running).

Comment: @fra-san More info: **1**. LightDM is _not_ running.  **2**. Xorg is _not_ running.  **3**. Looking at the output of `htop` in tree mode, most of the KDE services are grouped directly under `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user`.  The only services which do not appear as direct descendants of systemd are `/usr/bin/startplasma-x11` and its direct descendant `/usr/bin/plasma_session` and these two are grouped under chrome remote desktop! So could it be that because CRD needs to create Plasma sessions, the rest of Plasma gets loaded in as well by systemd?

Comment: Yep.  I just verified that when I connect with CRD from my Windows machine, I still get a KDE GUI even with systemd's boot target set to multi-user.  So that's it then.  All of KDE is running simply because I have Chrome Remote Desktop installed and by default it is configured to start a new session with every connection.  Perhaps if I reconfigured it to use an existing session, that would change and CRD would simply not work at all?

Comment: It's not clear to me: when systemd's default target is `multi-user`, is Plasma _always_ running after boot? Or is it only running after you connect to CRD? Can you connect to CRD if you aren't locally logged-in? And: is Plasma running if you don't log in locally as your user too?

Comment: I guess the CRD server process is started by means of the `chrome-remote-desktop.service` systemd user unit, activated by your user's systemd instance, which in turn is started by a PAM module when you log in (see [the doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User) for more on this.

Comment: @fra-san Yes, even when I am not locally logged in, Plasma is still already running after boot.  The `ps` listing I posted above was actually executed over SSH from Windows/Cygwin without logging in locally.  And you can indeed connect through CRD without being logged in locally as well.  Basically, the machine just has to be powered on and CRD will reliably produce a fresh KDE session every time you connect. It's pretty crazy.  It's not perfect of course, as certain icons aren't showing up either in my menu or my panel. But's it's a handy tool and it _works around the firewalls_.

Comment: An SSH login is still a login, i.e. it's enough to start your per-user systemd instance, which starts CRD and, as you find out, parts of your desktop environment. To check the sanity of your system you should try logging in, after a reboot, using an alternative user only, and look at the running process. Neither CRD nor Plasma-related processes nor a `systemd --user` process should be running for you usual user.